Type safety lost when passing a tRPC procedure to a function
I have an issue where I lose type safety of my tRPC procedure when I pass it as an argument to another function.
import {initTRPC, TRPCError, AnyProcedure} from "@trpc/server"
import * as zod from "zod";

const t = initTRPC.context<{}>().create();
export const publicProcedure = t.procedure;
type Proc = ReturnType<typeof publicProcedure.input>;

export const createTRPCEndpoint = <T extends Proc>(proc: T, _options: {}) => {
  return proc.use((opts) => opts.next({ ctx: { foo: 'foo' }}))
};

export const list = createTRPCEndpoint(
  publicProcedure.input(zod.object({ limit: zod.number().optional() })),
  {}
).query((opts) => {
  // expect limit to be typed correct; this should be an error because limit is `number | undefined`
  // instead, it's currently `any`
  // @ts-expect-error
  const _s1: string = opts.input?.limit;
  const _s2: string = opts.ctx.foo;
  return []
});

If it's helpful, I set up a TS playground here.
The issue is that with the definition of createTRPCEndpoint, the returned procedure loses the type definition of input.
It is important to be able to enrich the procedure ctx type with the middleware. If we didn't, we could override and cast the return type of createTRPCEndpoint as T, and then the type safety of input is preserved, but then we can't enrich the ctx type.
